# insert value array in database and next get(each) part of it?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use of codeigniter. how can insert several value (array) `<input name="ok[]">` in database and get they of database. (**what is the best way?**)

type rows in database is "VARCHAR" and "utf-8".

```
<input type="text" name="ok[]">
```

Values: (This is just one example of what I want)

```
ok[1] => hi, how are you?, 5426, assd, 54568
ok[2] => what, your name?, 548568a, 684a45ade
ok[3] => asdwhasdat, fine, 85as454se, 4e748sd
ok[3] => 85as454se, George, asdwhasdat, 4e748sd
Etc. ....
```

Now after it, i want inputs `ok[1], ok[2], ok[3]` together insert in a row (column) on database.

**NEXT:**
I want get (the second part) they of database and each they in foreach as:

> how are you? 
>  fine
>  your name? 
>  George

how is it?

Comment: It's very hard to understand what do you want. You should give some background and more details (DB type?).

Answer (score 0):

```
$inserts = array();

foreach ($_REQUEST['ok'] as $key => $val)
{
   $parts = explode(',', $val);
   $inserts[] = "('" . mysql_real_escape_string($parts[1]) . "')";
}

$inserts = implode(',', $inserts);
$sql = "INSERT INTO yourtable (fieldname) VALUES $inserts;";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: No, i don't want insert only part 1, i want insert all(with `serialize()` or `json_encode` or any function other best). Next: i want get(select) only part 2 of `ok[1], ok[2], ok[3]` of database. how is in codeigniter?